# Why html can´t read this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to recreate the google main page however my problem is with the I am feeling lucky button when I press the I am feeling lucky button the function `luck()` is not being recognized.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError TypeError: luck is not a function

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="combinados.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function luck() {
                var query = document.querySelector(".search").value;
                window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&btnI";
            };
         </script>

    </head>
    <body >
        <form class="bar" action="https://www.google.com/search">
            <input class="search" type="text" name="q">
            <input id ="search" type="submit" value="Google Search">
            <input id ="luck" type="button" value="I am feeling lucky" onclick="luck()">
            
        </form>
        <ul id="links">
            <li><a href="imagesearch.html">Image Search </a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="advancedsearch.html">Advanced Search </a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: change the name of the function or the id of the `<input>` so that they are not both called "luck"

Comment: @Pointy that was fast bro thanks

Comment: That's what I do bro

Comment: @Pointy almost all of the search query gets thrown into the first-page but others don't. why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have the id of the `<input>`, and function name is same. So, when the button is clicked, the browser tries to execute the `luck()` function but there's an HTML element with the id of `luck`, which creates confusion.

To fix this, you can either change you function name or `<input>` id.

Here's an example where I changed the function name to `feelingLucky()`.

```html
<input id="luck" type="button" value="I am feeling lucky" onclick="feelingLucky()">
```

```js
function feelingLucky() {
    var query = document.querySelector(".search").value;
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&btnI";
};
```